# Two port NIC, one port works

Tags: networking, 20.04

I have a simple two port NIC plugged directly into an Ubuntu 20.04 computer. One port works. `ip a` shows one port (ENPxxB) up and one (ENPxxA) down.

Nothing I've tried (`sudo ifconfig ENPxxA up` or `sudo ip link set ENPxxA up`) works. ENPxxA remains down. It's not hardware, I've replaced the NIC with no change.

My mainboard is an [Asus B450M](https://www.asus.com/motherboards-components/motherboards/prime/prime-b450m-a/techspec/), CPU is AMD Ryzen 5600G.

A little more detail:

From the `.yaml` file:

```
network:
 ethernets:

    enp4s0f0:
      addresses: [169.254.10.20/24]
    enp4s0f1:
      addresses: [169.254.100.20/24]
```

From `ip -a`:

```
enp4s0f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:b7:85:01:da:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

enp4s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:b7:85:01:da:9b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.100.20/24 brd 169.254.100.255 scope global enp4s0f1
```

So even though `enp4s0f0` has an IP address assigned, it does not show up in `ip -a` or `ifconfig` and the port is shown as down.

How can I get that port up? Any suggestions are most welcome.

---

A little more detail:
From the .yaml file -
network:
ethernets:

```
enp4s0f0:
  addresses: [169.254.10.20/24]
enp4s0f1:
  addresses: [169.254.100.20/24]
```

From ip -a:

enp4s0f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 98:b7:85:01:da:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

enp4s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 98:b7:85:01:da:9b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 169.254.100.20/24 brd 169.254.100.255 scope global enp4s0f1

So even though enp4s0f0 has an ip address assigned, it does not show in (ip a)(or ifconfig) and the port is shown as down.

How can I get that port up?

Comment: How can I read answer 1496838? I have no idea what "as supplemental" means

Comment: Do you have a cable connected to the 2nd port and plugged into a switch/router/something? eg, do you have link lights on both ?

Comment: HDHomeruns are connected to each port per instructions for direct connect to PC. Regardless of which HDHomerun is connected to which port, it is always enp4s0f0 that is down. The one connected to enprs0f1 works fine.